# Some detail questions about K mean algorithm

Tags: algorithms

Question is how to set Kmeans algorithm K, what kind of data set is applicable, how to evaluate Kmeans clustering results, and how to judge whether the LR and Kmeans algorithms implemented by myself are correct?

For how to set K, I think we can compare intra-class distance and inter-class distance to determine K. And we also can use the algorithm based on consistency matrix: that is, when the correct K is obtained, the results of different clustering will be more similar to determine K. And based on hierarchical clustering: that is, based on the idea of merging or splitting, it stops under certain circumstances to obtain K.

But I don't know what kind of data set is applicable. And how to evaluate Kmeans clustering results, and how to judge whether the LR and Kmeans algorithms implemented by myself are correct?

Thanks

Comment: What is LR, logistic regression? Likelihood ratio?

Comment: Have you seen *Elements of Statistical Learning*? It covers K-means and clustering in general pretty thoroughly... https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/ESLII.pdf